# Can't ping Ubuntu Server from Outside network

Tags: networking, server, webserver

Just finished setting up my Ubuntu Server 12.04 as a web server at my house with broadband. Everything is setup and works just fine until I tried to access it from outside.

The public IP for the machine (and also my router's) is 139.228.159.132, and I can ping it and also view the website when I'm connected under the same network via wifi. But when I try to access it via other network at the office, it won't respond, RTO.

I already set a static IP via /etc/network/interfaces but it still won't work, been 2 days since I'm stuck at this problem. Anyone can help? Thank!

FYI, I have also add port range forwarding 22-80 to my specific machine (192.168.1.113) on my linksys router.

Comment: Can your server connect to the outside (updates, browsing, etc.)?

Comment: Yes. It seems like my router is blocking inbound pings but I have all the port forwarding set up. can't seem to figure out why..

Answer (score 0):

Ping uses the ICMP protocol, not TCP, so port forwarding is not at all relevant with ping replies. Ping is just a first diagnostic tool, sometimes you don't get a reply but still everything seems to work fine... The webserver is up, you can connect through ftp and ssh, so no problem.

You could use NAT but i am guessing it is a home network and 139.228.159.132 is your only public IP address, so it's not a good idea.

Check whether your router has any settings for ICMP requests. If not that's as much as you can do about it. You can live without ping replies :-)